# RoundCube Password Configuration Plugin with Multiple Cpanel Accounts

Tags: php, cpanel, roundcube

I have multiple cpanel accounts that I want to use the password change plugin for RoundCube. In the config.inc.php file for the plugin (as seen below), I included a function to set the configuration variables, which consolidates the code (see the case statement for what I mean).

I've tried returning the function array, adding global variables, and much more. Much to my demise, I am unable to get the password plugin to understand that the variables are configured. I printed the results to a log file inside the switch statements (at one point) and it returned every variable defined inside the function. But, for some reason, the plugin is not getting those variables inside the password.php file.

The result on the user end is that the password change fails with an error message.

```
// Password Plugin options
    $rcmail_config['password_driver'] = 'cpanel';

// LOAD USER CONFIGURATION
    global $CONFIG, $RCMAIL;
    $rcmail = rcmail::get_instance();
    $user = $rcmail->user;

// GET THE USER'S DOMAIN NAME
function getDomainFromEmail($email)
{
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
    return $domain;
}


// CONFIGURE PASSWORD PLUG-IN BASED ON THE EMAIL DOMAIN NAME
function setConfiguration($password_cpanel_host, $password_cpanel_username, $password_cpanel_password, $password_cpanel_port, $password_cpanel_ssl, $password_cpanel_theme)
{   global $rcmail, $rcmail_config;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_host']      = $password_cpanel_host;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_username']  = $password_cpanel_username;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_password']  = $password_cpanel_password;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_port']      = $password_cpanel_port;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_ssl']       = $password_cpanel_ssl;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_theme']     = $password_cpanel_theme;

    //return $rcmail_config;    
}

// CHECK THE DOMAIN NAME AND APPLY THE PLUG-IN SETTINGS
switch (getDomainFromEmail($user->get_username()))
{
case "domain1.com":
    // DOES NOT WORK WHEN DEFINED THIS WAY (AFTER RETURN IS UNCOMMENTED IN FUNCTION)
    $rcmail_config = setConfiguration('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 2083, true, 'x3');
    // OR THIS WAY
    setConfiguration('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 2083, true, 'x3');

    break;

case "domain2.org":
    // WORKS WHEN DEFINED THIS WAY
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_host']      = 'xxx';
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_username']  = 'xxx';
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_password']  = 'xxx';
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_port']      = '2083';
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_ssl']       = true;
    $rcmail_config['password_cpanel_theme']     = 'x3';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this issue already but I came across exactly the same problem and have solved it with a little help from the cPanel community. The one scenario I couldn't get working (but eventually did) was when a parked domain was used

You will need to use the WHM login details rather than cPanel login details then use port 2087 as you're completing as an admin. I hope this helps.

I've posted the final code here

http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/finding-account-username-parked-domain-428501.html